# Length of this representation increases really slowly?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, prime-factorization

$$\def\'{\text{'}}\def\len{\operatorname{len}}$$
A [recent Code Golf challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/254870/base-neutral-numbering-system) introduced a "base neutral numbering system". Here I present a slightly modified version, but the idea is the same:

> Let $f(n)$ be constructed as follows: i) $f(1)$ is the empty string; ii) let $2=p_1<p_2<\cdots$ be all the prime numbers; if $i$ is the smallest positive integer such that $p_i \mid n$, then $f(n)$ is $`(\' \ast f(i) \ast `)\' \ast f(n / p_i)$, where `*` denotes string concatenation.

For example, $9 = 3 \times 3$, $3 = p_2$, $2 = p_1$. Therefore $f(9) = (())(())$.

<sup>Simply this is fun</sup> I calculated the first 50000 values for $f(n)$, and found something interesting: the length of the string is *really small*. The record values for $n \le 50000$ are:

```
n f(n) len(f(n))
2 () 2
3 (()) 4
5 ((())) 6
9 (())(()) 8
15 (())((())) 10
25 ((()))((())) 12
45 (())(())((())) 14
75 (())((()))((())) 16
125 ((()))((()))((())) 18
225 (())(())((()))((())) 20
375 (())((()))((()))((())) 22
625 ((()))((()))((()))((())) 24
1125 (())(())((()))((()))((())) 26
1875 (())((()))((()))((()))((())) 28
3125 ((()))((()))((()))((()))((())) 30
5625 (())(())((()))((()))((()))((())) 32
9375 (())((()))((()))((()))((()))((())) 34
15625 ((()))((()))((()))((()))((()))((())) 36
28125 (())(())((()))((()))((()))((()))((())) 38
46875 (())((()))((()))((()))((()))((()))((())) 40
```

And the record value seems to be reached only if $v_5(n)$ is large.

**Question.** How slow (or fast?) does the length of $f(n)$ increases? I'd like to see an accurate answer, but any bound (weak or sharp) is appreciated. Also, explain why $f(n)$ takes record value only for multiples of $5$ (or even $25$).

---

**Edit 1.** As observed by Ross Millikan, I calculated

$$\frac{\len f(p_i)}{\ln p_i} \text{ for all $i \le 1500$.}$$

And really this value seems to have a global maximum at $p_i=5$ (reached `3.72800960735767`, while others, especially for larger $i$'s, don't even exceed 3). This empirical observation might solve the second question.

---

**Edit 2.** If we assume that $\len f(n) < c\ln n$ for all $n \le k$, we have
$$\len f(p_k) = 2 + \len f(k) < 2 + c\ln n < c\ln(n\ln n)$$
for a constant, large-enough $c$. I think this idea might be able to extend to the general case, by induction.

Comment: Just a guess: $\operatorname{len}(f(n)) = O(\ln n)$.

Comment: What happened to $7$?  Shouldn't it have length $8$?  Shouldn't $49$ have length $16?$  These seem like they should be records.

Comment: @RossMillikan $f(7)=(()())$ since $7 = p_4 = p_{2 \times 2} = p_{p_1 \cdot p_1}$.

Comment: Starting from $5^1$ the pattern seems to be $5^a,3^25^{(a-1)},3\cdot 5^a,5^{(a+1)},3^25^a,3\cdot 5^{(a+1)}$ and so on.  You take out one factor of $5$, costing $6$, and add $3^2$ which gives $8$ for a net of $2$.  Then you take out a $3$, costing $4$ and put in a $5$ which gives $6$ for a net of $2$ twice.

Comment: Why downvote? Please give some suggestions so that I can improve the post.

Comment: Don't worry too much about downvotes unless you get a negative comment.  Sometimes they just happen.  We have a policy against questions with no effort shown.  I think you have shown significant effort, but someone may disagree. I hit you with a +1 which will do as much as five downvotes.  I got one, too.

Answer (score 3):

The primes $2,3,5,7,11$ take $2,4,6,6,8$ characters to represent them.  For a composite you just stack the prime representations together.  If a number has factorization $2^a3^b5^c7^d11^e$ the length of its representation is $2a+4b+6c+6d+8e$.  This explains the slow growth of the expressions.  The length of the expression is a few times the logarithm of the number and logarithms grow very slowly.

To see why powers of $5$ set records for length, let us look at $2^7=128$ and $5^3=125$.  The numbers are almost equal, but the length for $128$ is $14$ and the length for $125$ is $18$.  Each prime factor brings a contribution to the length.  You can take the log of the number of interest and the logs of the prime factors will add up to it.  Each prime $p_i$ has a figure of merit $\frac {\operatorname {len}p_i}{\log p_i}$  Using base $10$ logs we see
$$\begin {array} {r | r |r} \text {prime} &\operatorname {len}p_i & \frac{\operatorname {len}p_i}{\log p_i} \\
\hline 2&2&6.64\\3&4&8.38\\5&6&8.58\\7&6&7.10\\11&8&7.68
\end {array}$$

We see that over this range $5$ gives us more length for its log than any other prime.  I have not shown that it beats larger primes but I believe the slow growth will make it so.